# Groovy: Proper usage of if else

Tags: groovy

I have this groovy code which works fine by itself:

```
    def msg = "$evt.displayName was locked7 ${userName ? "by " + userName + " " : ""}$lockMode" // Default message to send
```

When I put it inside this simple if else block, it doesn't work at all (neither the first condition nor the else condition do anything).

```
    if (i == 999) { //For Schlage One touch lock function
        def msg = "$evt.displayName was locked via One Touch" // Default message to send
    } else {
        def msg = "$evt.displayName was locked7 ${userName ? "by " + userName + " " : ""}$lockMode" // Default message to send
    }
```

Is there something incorrect in my code?

Comment: What is the issue / error as you said that doesn't working  ?

Comment: No error. It just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Where the execution going in if or else?

Comment: When I use it out of the if else statement and I turn the lock, I get a push notification, but nothing happens when it's inside the statement.

Comment: This doesn't seems complete code, 'def msg' should be the global variable

Comment: @CreativeMind Have you tried with my answer..?

Comment: Yes, testing, still got some issues, but could be other reason. Be back shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the single line statement after  if or else condition you can use if..else statement without {}, for multiple statements you must need to use curly braces {}.

```
    def msg = ""
    int i = 999
    if (i == 999) 
       msg = "$evt.displayName was locked via One Touch" // Default message to send
    else 
       msg = "$evt.displayName was locked7 ${userName ? "by " + userName + " " : ""}$lockMode" // Default message to send

    println "MESSAGE: "+msg
```

Comment: Thanks. So def can not be put inside the if else statement?

Comment: Yes, because it will not be resolve the outside the block

Comment: Thanks. The issue was with the def, not the braces btw

Answer (score 0):

For more information about your question,

1. `def` a variable inside `if` or `else` not works outside (your question scenario)
2. Making global `def` works everywhere (wkt).
3. You can use a variable in global even without `def` them like below shown code.
   **code:**

without def msg

```
int i=999
if (i==999)
msg = "$evt.displayName was locked via One Touch" // Default message to send
else 
msg = "$evt.displayName was locked7 ${userName ? "by " + userName + " " : ""}$lockMode" // Default message to send    
println "MESSAGE: "+msg
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)